# How do I store each element of a List in a Data Frame, when the lists elements are pages of text that need to be parsed?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dataframe, split

I have a list with several elements in it.  Each element is essentially a page from a scraped PDF file converted to string using OCR and Tesseract.

I'd like to split each page into lines then store all of this in a data frame.  I'd like the end structure to be "columns are pages" and "rows are lines."

I know that the following will take a single page and store each row in a data frame.

```
page1 = pd.DataFrame(final_text[0].splitlines())
```

I also know that I can take the pages in final text and store them as columns in a data frame using the following:

```
pages = pd.DataFrame(final_text).T
```

My problem is two fold:

1. How do I write a for loop that will do both of the above actions for all elements in final_text?
2. The for loop would need to take into account that each element or page will result in a different number of rows.  Pandas requires same number of rows to append to a data frame.

I've tried a number of things with no success, any help or direction would be appreciated.

Mostly experimenting along these lines

```
for page in pages:
     page.splitlines()
```

But this pulls the index value and not the actual element.  Gives the following error:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Comment: Can you post what have you tried as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I ended up solving the problem.

```
# Determine the longest page value
page_length = []

for page in final_text:
    page_length.append(len(page.split('\n')))

page_length_max = max(page_length)

# Add blank lines to list entries so they equal the page with max length
updated_text = []

for page in final_text:
    updated_text.append(page.split('\n') + list(((page_length_max - len(page.split('\n'))) * '\n')))

# Create a dataframe with each page a column and each row and line
data = pd.DataFrame()

for i, page in enumerate(updated_text):
     data['page_%s' %str(i+1)] = page
```